# Match curly brace wrapped characters in a slash delimited string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match a substring which contains no curly braces or forward slashes AND is wrapped by curly braces THEN wrapped by delimiting forward slashes.

Pseudocode: `/{ any string not contain "/" and "{" and "}" inside }/`

My test string `/a/{bb}/{d{b}}/{as}df}/b{cb}/a{sdfas/dsgf}`

My failed pattern: `\/\{((?!\/).)*\}\/`

My failed result:

```
array(2)
    =>  array(2)
        =>  /{bb}/
        =>  /{as}df}/
    )
    =>  array(2)
        =>  b
        =>  f
    )
)
```

I want it to only match `/{bb}/` and isolate `bb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```
(?<=\/){[^\/{}]*?}(?=\/)
```

> Explanation

- `(?<=\/)` - Positive look  behind. Matches `/`
- `{` - Matches `{`.
- `[^\/{}]*?` - Matches everything except `{` and `}` and `/` zero or more time ( lazy mode ).
- `(?=\/)` - Matches `/`.

You can use this too `\/({[^\/{}]*?})\/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8U6qA/2)

Answer (score 1):

I extremely suggest you to use https://regex101.com/ website to test and debug your regex

this regex will work for you: (?<=/){([^/{}]+?)}(?=/)

[image: screenshot of regex101 website]

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the whole substring between delimiting slashes is a solitary value wrapped in curly braces, I recommend that you check that:

1. the match starts with a delimiting slash or is at the start of the string and
2. the curly-brace-wrapped value does not contain any delimiting slashes or curly braces and
3. the match is immediately followed by a delimiting slash or is at the end of the string.

Lazy matching is not necessary/beneficial in the pattern because the negated character class will prevent the possibility of "over matching".

Cod: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7u7l4))

```
$string = '/a/{bb}/{d{b}}/{as}df}/b{cb}/a{sdfas/dsgf}';

var_export(
    preg_match(
        '~(?:^|/){([^{}/]*)}(?:/|$)~',
        $string,
        $out
    )
    ? $out
    : 'no match'
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '/{bb}/',    // the fullstring match
  1 => 'bb',        // capture group 1
)
```